# Update ListView after initialising CursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-cursoradapter

I have a Tabs Activity that contains Fragments for tabs.  One of the tabs displays a list of data from a SQLite databse table (or a different Fragment if the table is empty).  When initially creating the tabs, the Tabs Activity checks to see if the table contains any data.  If it does, then it initialises the list Fragment but doesn't set up the CursorAdapter.  The CursorAdapter is initialised by an AsyncTask which syncs the SQLite database with a central database, and then creates the Cursors and CursorAdapters.  The list Fragment displays a ProgressDialog while waiting for the AsyncTask to create the CursorAdapter.  When the CurserAdapter is initialised, the ProgressDialog is dismissed but the ListView remains on its 'empty list' view, despite calls to notifyDataSetChanged(). If I switch tabs and come back, the ListView displays the data correctly.  How can I make the ListView update once the CursorAdapter has been initialised?

**Relevant bits of code:**

Tabs:

```
private static ImageCursorAdapter friendCursorAdapter = null;

public static ImageCursorAdapter getFriendsListAdapter() {
    return friendCursorAdapter;
}

public static void setFriendsListAdapter(ImageCursorAdapter adapter) {
    friendCursorAdapter = adapter;
    friendCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

SyncTask:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_TABLE_NAME;
    statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
    count = statement.simpleQueryForLong();         
    if(count>0) {
        friendCursor = db.query(WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_FIRST_NAME_COLUMN+", "+WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_LAST_NAME_COLUMN);
    }
    statement.close();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
    if(friendCursor!=null) {
        ImageCursorAdapter adapter = new ImageCursorAdapter(WhereWolfActivity.this, friendCursor, 0, ImageCursorAdapter.FRIENDS);
        Tabs.setFriendsListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

FriendsList:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(Tabs.getFriendsListAdapter());
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(Tabs.getFriendsListAdapter()==null) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), getString(R.string.loadingtitle), getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(Tabs.getFriendsListAdapter()==null) {}
                dialog.dismiss();             
                Tabs.getFriendsListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        thread.start();         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new adapter, but I don't see any code to set the adapter to the list. Since the list knows nothing about your brand new adapter, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't help. BTW, if you are already using fragments, you might consider using a Loader.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I missed that bit out. I have added it to the FriendsList code. I considered using a CursorLoader but I don't have the database set up as a ContentProvider as it's a private database.

Comment: Did that solve your problem? BTW, you can easily write a Loader that supports your custom database. Just copy the CursorLoader source code and replace the ContentProvider part with your custom implementation. Here's a sample: http://code.google.com/p/wwwjdic/source/browse/branches/2.0/wwwjdic/src/org/nick/wwwjdic/history/HistoryLoaderBase.java

Comment: No I didn't. I've started looking into Loaders and looks like that might be the solution, although I am currently confused by them :-)

Comment: That's strange. My code is largely similar (except for a call to `startManagingCursor()`) to yours and seems to work OK. Getting this sort of thing right with the old API's is actually a lot trickier than with loaders, so definitely worth your time.

Comment: Got to grips with Loaders, code's now working brilliantly (although I haven't yet put the ProgressDialog back in) - thanks for your help